# create JSON from list

Tags: python, json

i have list

```
li = ['Peter', '22', 'DE']
```

and i want to create json from this list so i need to add to every parameter in list a name, so outpur will be something like this

```
li = ['name':'Peter', 'age':'22', 'nationality':'DE']

i = 0
while i < len(li):
    li[i].insert(0,'name:')
    i += 1
print(li)
```

this adding to every added name a coma...how can i add to this list without comma?
because output from this is :

```
['name','Peter', '22', 'DE']
```

Comment: 1. You operate on the list, while you want a dictionary. 2. List is already a valid json. `import json` `json.dumps(li)` will dump it into json string

Comment: Anyway in which python version you are able to execute this? Isn't it throwing error?

Comment: You realize that this `li = ['name':'Peter', 'age':'22', 'nationality':'DE']` is *not* valid Python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`li` is the list object which you are iterating over so any operations on that will act as operations performed over the list.

`insert()` will insert elements in the existing list.

You can use `zip()` with `dict()` after creating the keys for the dictionary to get the desired output:

```
li = ['Peter', '22', 'DE']
keys = ['name', 'age', 'nationality']
di = dict(zip(keys, li))
```

---

Update: You can use list comprehension for list of lists:

```
li = [ ['Peter', '22', 'DE'], ['John', '28', 'GB'] ]
keys = ['name', 'age', 'nationality']
di = [dict(zip(keys, l)) for l in li]
print(di)
```

Comment: this is super but if i have li = [ ['Peter', '22', 'DE'], ['John', '28', 'GB'] ]
is it possible to use it in this tipe of lists?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), to combine all values of both lists and convert it to a dict:

```
li = ['Peter', '22', 'DE']
keys = ['name', 'age', 'nationality']
print(dict(zip(keys, li)))
```

Out:

```
{'name': 'Peter', 'age': '22', 'nationality': 'DE'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate Keys and then map those keys with value present in the list to create a dictionary convert dictionary to JSON

```
ky = ['Name', 'Age', 'Nationality']
li = ['Peter', '22', 'DE']
data = {k:v for (k,v) in zip(ky, li)}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not a list, but a dictionary. Dictionaries are collections paired with keys and values:

```py
my_dict = {"name" : "Peter", "age" : 22, "nationality" : "DE"}
```

If you need to build a dictionary over a list, you can do it with `zip()` method:

```py
li = ['Peter', '22', 'DE']
keys = ["name", 'age', 'nationality']
 
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, li)) # {'name': 'Peter', 'age': '22', 'nationality': 'DE'}
```

If you **really** need to work with [JSON files](https://appdividend.com/2019/04/15/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-json-tutorial-with-example/#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20Python%20dict%20to,the%20json(dictionary)%20object!), then i suggest looking into this link for a clear explanation.